# Required value: tasklist

Tags: gmail, google-tasks-api

Following the instructions here:
http://www.pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/ I am trying to set up my gmail account so that I can email tasks to myself. However, using the included code and only modifying the TASKLIST global from DJ's name to my own (it doesn't work with his either), I receive the error

> Required value: tasklist (line 65, file "Code")

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have enabled the Tasks API and entered my API key.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue logged here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-tasks-api/LmtPEHIB6DA

In my case the syntax was wrong...

the syntax is 
update(taskObject, tasklistID, taskID)

Try
var update = Tasks.Tasks.update(body={"status":taskStatus,"id":taskId}, taskListId, taskId);